# Contardor Frecuencia usando ficheros c++

Tags: c++

Buenas

Estoy realizando un contador de frecuencia, donde indicando la dirección del fichero (txt) muestre cuales son las letras que aparecen y la cantidad de veces que aparezcan en el texto. El problema que tengo es en el contador el cual no muestra las letras encontradas ni la cantidad de caracteres repetidos.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void contar(char frase[], char diccionario[], int);
int letras;

main(){
    FILE *archivo;
   char frase[100], diccionario[86] ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz0123456789áéí[]{}/%!$&:;,.<>=?¿'" ;
   int caracter,caracteres,i;



   cout<<"Ingrese la direccion sin la extension (.txt):\n";
   gets(frase);
   strcat(frase,".txt");
   archivo=fopen(frase, "r");

   while((caracter = fgetc(archivo)) != EOF){
    printf("%c", caracter);
    letras++;
    for(i=0;i<86;i++){
        contar(frase, diccionario,i);
    }
   }

   printf("\n\n\nLa cantidad de letras es: %d",letras);
   fclose(archivo);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}

void contar(char frase[], char diccionario[],int i){
  int j,num,contador;
  char letra;
  num = letras;
  for(j=0;j<num-1;j++){
    if(frase[j]==diccionario[i]){
    contador+=1;
      letra = diccionario[i];
   }
  }
  if (contador !=0){
    printf("el numero de letras %c es %d\n", letra, contador);
  }
}
```

Esto es lo que el programa me muestra en ejecución cuando uso un archivo el cual tiene la palabra "anona"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es c++? parece C.. en realidad parece una mezcla entre ambos, como si tomaras partes de un código un C y lo implantaras en c++

Dejame adivinar... El archivo que estas leyendo comienza por la letra l?

El problema que veo es en los argumentos que estas pasando a la función `contar`

```
        // frase es el nombre del archivo, no su contenido
        contar(frase, diccionario,i);
```

Para poder enviar el contenido a la función contar tienes que en primer lugar almacenarla

```
// almaceno el archivo dentro de frase
letras = 0;
while((caracter = fgetc(archivo)) != EOF)
{
    printf("%c", caracter);
    frase[letras] = caracter
    letras++;
}
// luego y fuera del while verifico las letras de frase 
for(i=0;i<86;i++)
{
    contar(frase, diccionario,i);
}
```

Esto debería solucionar tu problema tal como esta planteado, sin embargo creo que podrias hacer uso de la libreria `#include <string>` para manejar las cadenas de caracteres y de la libreria `#include <fstream>` para manejar archivos y podria ser más sencillo sin embargo *esto es una opinion.*

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @Jacoboc me ayudo tu respuesta, tomando en cuenta claro que también tuve que iniciar la variable contador a cero para que no me mostrara el "4239736".

Comment: Ahhh.. claro. ese detalle no lo vi. que bueno que pudiste resolverlo. Si consideras que la respuesta te ayudo, puedes darle un voto arriba, y si consideras que es la solución también puedes marcarla como solución.